# Regex Matching in golang

Tags: go

How do you match the string `ello w` in `hello world`

Got to this error from trying this [example](https://play.golang.org/p/W_1rE0IxB7f)

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"

)

func check(result string  ) string {
    
    if (regexp.MatchString("b\\ello w\\b",result)) {
        fmt.Println("Found it ")
        return "True"
    } else {
        return "False"
    }
}

func main() {
    text := "Hello world "
    check (text)
    
}
```

throws the following error

```
# command-line-arguments
.\test.go:14:5: multiple-value regexp.MatchString() in single-value context
```

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't throw the same error. It simply prints `false <nil>`, Also you don't call `check` function from your main. Please share a reproducible example

Comment: I am learning about the ```regexp```  and i used the example in that link to write the script that throws the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regexp.MatchString` returns two value. When you use it in your `if` conditional, compiler fails.

You should assign the return values first, then handle error case and then the match case

By the way your regex was also faulty, please see the code for a correct one for your case

https://play.golang.org/p/dNEsa9mIfhE

```
func check(result string  ) string {
    // faulty regex   
    // m, err := regexp.MatchString("b\\ello w\\b",result)
    m, err := regexp.MatchString("ello w",result)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("your regex is faulty")
      // you should log it or throw an error 
      return err.Error()
    }
    if (m) {
        fmt.Println("Found it ")
        return "True"
    } else {
        return "False"
    }
}

func main() {
    text := "Hello world "
    check(text)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MatchString() returns 2 values, a bool and an error, so your if statement doesn't know how to process that. https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#MatchString

In the correction below, I just through away the error value but I would recommend actually checking and handling the error.

https://play.golang.org/p/awAFxxAMyWl

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"

)

func check(result string  ) string {
    
found, _:= regexp.MatchString(`ello w`,result)    
if (found) {
        fmt.Println("Found it ")
        return "True"
    } else {
        return "False"
    }
}

func main() {
    
    text := "Hello world "

    fmt.Println(check(text))
    
}
```